# Passing Vector of Struct to Function

Tags: c++

I'm struggling to figure out how to pass a Vector of a Struct to a function in an easy and elegant way. The code looks like this:

```
struct cube{ double width; double length; double height; };
vector<cube> myVec;
int myFunc(vector<double> &in)
{
// do something here
}
int test = myFunc(myVec.width); // NOT POSSIBLE
```

So what I want is to pass just the vector of widths to the function and perform some calculations. Is this at all possible or do I have to pass the complete vector fo struct to the function myFunc()?

Comment: Is `myFunc` going to modify the `double`s? Or just access them?

Comment: As you're passing by reference, it doesn't matter if you pass the whole vector, even if you only use a sub-set of fields in the structs.

Comment: Good problem. I think you have to create a separate Vector first and then pass it.. Or you have to pass "myVec" completely.

Comment: without extraction into a separate vector, you can't do it. There a heaps of ways to do *that*, but it has to be done one way or another unless you're willing to change the required type of the `myFunc` parameter to a `vector<cube>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to perform some computations with one of the struct's field, then you must tell  `myFunc` what field it needs to use. Like this:

```
void myFunc( std::vector< cube > & vect, double cube::*field ) {
    for ( cube & c : vect ) {
        c.*field // <--- do what you want
    }
}
// calling
myFunc( myVect, & cube::width );
myFunc( myVect, & cube::length );
// etc.
```

BTW, even if fields are different type, but they can be used in formula inside `myFunc`, you still can use `myFunc` by making it template:

```
template< typename FieldType >
void myFunc( std::vector< cube > & vect, FieldType cube::*field ) {
    for ( cube & c : vect ) {
        c.*field // <--- do what you want
    }
}
// calling will be similar to the first piece
```

Comment: Oh, nice. Remind me what that `cube::*field` thing is properly called, please?

Comment: @Roddy the pointer to member. It could be either field or function

Comment: @TomKnapen sorry for rejected your edit, but I added some stuff about template after your changes. Nevertheless I edited answer following your suggestions. Thank you

Comment: @borisbn no problem, just change `cube c : vect` in your second example to `cube & c : vect` to avoid additional copying

Comment: @borisbn why two structure fields are not passed at the same time with one function call?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new vector containing all the `width` elements in the `myVec` vector.

You could use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to do it.

```
std::vector<cube> myVec;
std::vector<double> myWidthVector;

std::transform(std::begin(myVec), std::end(myVec),
               std::back_inserter(myWidthVector),
               [](const cube& c) { return c.width; });

myFunc(myWidthVector);
```

Comment: ... and transform it back into the cube vector after the call, as myFunc param is not const.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the vector as you are doing in myFunc already. But, as you are passing a reference, there is no additional overhead induced. Within the function you can call

```
in[position].width;
```

or similar.

Edit: As Aloc pointed out: If you are not going to change the contents, you should pass a reference to a const.